Question about a theorem of automorphism on field
This is a trivial question but I couldn't find any satisfying answers, please enlighten me.
The theorem states: "If K is a field and if $σ_1,..., σ_n$ are distinct automorphisms of K, then it is impossible to find elements $α_1,..., α_n,$ not all $0$, in K such that $α_1σ_1(u)$ + $α_2σ_2(u)$ + ... + $α_nσ_n(u)$ = $0$ for all $u$ ∈ K.
But I see a conflicting example. Let F be the field of real number, let $ω = e^{2πi/3}$ and let $σ_i$ be an automorphism in K = F($ω$). Then it is known that $σ_1(1)$, $σ_2(1)$, $σ_3(1)$ are 3rd roots of unity and $ω$, $ω^2$, 1 forms a basis for K. Then we can choose $α_1$ = $α_2$ = $α_3$ to get:
$σ_1(1)α_1$ + $σ_2(1)α_2$ + $σ_3(1)α_3$ = $0$
$σ_1(ω)α_1$ + $σ_2(ω)α_2$ + $σ_3(ω)α_3$ = $0$
$σ_1(ω^2)α_1$ + $σ_2(ω^2)α_2$ + $σ_3(ω^2)α_3$ = $0$
Since every element in F is of form $u$ = $b_1$ + $b_2ω$ + $b_3ω^2$ with $b_1,b_2,b_3$ in F. From above equations we get:
$α_1σ_1(u)$ + $α_2σ_2(u)$ + $α_3σ_3(u)$ = $0$, which contradicts the theorem.
Please help me find the flaws in my reasoning or point out how I misunderstand the theorem. Or maybe explain how you intepret this theorem.

Please do not answer in the comments, @JyrkiLahtonen.

Very sorry about failing to play by the rules here, Shaun. I'm trying to learn this. As I recall it, I initially felt that I can just explain one thing to the asker. Hoping they would see the light. I  felt that my comment failed to answer the (IMHO the crucial) question in the last sentence, so I thought it would be ok to leave a comment only. I have a lot of baggage like this.

The problem starts with this sentence:

Then it is known that $σ_1(1)$, $σ_2(1)$, $σ_3(1)$ are 3rd roots of unity and $ω$, $ω^2$, 1 forms a basis for K.

The second half of this sentence is false, since $K$ is a two-dimensional extension of the ground field. (The putative basis is not linearly independent, since $1 + \omega + \omega^2 = 0$.) The first half of the sentence is techncially true but probability not what you meant: if $\sigma$ is any automorphism of any field, it fixes the element $1$ (which is indeed a third root of unity, but a trivial one).
